# If/Then Statement in ArcMap to Remove Duplicates

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, field-calculator, if-statement

I need help writing an if/then statement in ArcMap 10.5.

Scenario:
I generated a near table, but since the closest features (polylines) were mostly all overlapping with the input (multipoints), the table "ranked" the outputs as tying since the distances were zero.

I would like to re-rank these values so that the rank # is always unique, as I need to convert this near table into a pivot table next. It doesn't matter what ranking they get, as they're technically all the same distance.

Any ideas for an expression to rewrite the ranking # if there are duplicates, or a different workaround?

Example:
IN_FID 2 found three features that were within my search radius. Instead of listing them as rank 1, 2, 3 it's listing it as 1, 1, 2 because the Near_Dist is 0. I just want a way to re-rank these so that the table doesn't have rank numbers that tie, like how this example has two "1"s. These can be arbitrary numbers, and don't need to be in this field. I just need a field to give a unique number between 1 and 3 for every IN_FID in this Near Table.

[image: Example]

Comment: How will you be using the pivot table? If the ranking doesn't matter, then what do you expect to learn from a pivot table with arbitrary values?

Comment: I will be joining the near table using the FIDs with another table that has values for daily traffic numbers before I make a pivot table. So, basically the issue I am having is with pivot table outputting correctly. Since one FID has three values listed as "2" for rank in the near table, my pivot table still has extra lines for the one FID. I just need to fix this relationship.

Comment: I should clarify - the ranking matters - I found the closest features by using the generate near table. But, now that I have the near table generated, the ranking no longer matters in the context that I already found the closest features.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you just want to run [DeleteIdentical](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-identical.htm) to remove the duplicates.

Comment: Well, I want to keep all the values. They are different objects, I just want an automated way to change the ranking numbers. That way I can use that field to pivot.

Comment: Could you edit the post to describe what shape types your data are and what real-world features they represent. It sounds like we might have the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Just added an example with some more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use arcpy. `updatefield` will be overwritten so backup your data (or add a new field to fill with new values) before running the code in the python window of ArcMap.

```py
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\data.gdb\Intersections_MP_Carver_Gene' #Change to match your data
idfield = 'IN_FID' #Change to match your data
updatefield = 'NEAR_RANK' #Change to match your data

def times_so_far(ls):
    out = [0]*len(ls)
    for i in xrange(len(ls)):
        out[i] = ls[:i].count(ls[i])+1
    return out

ids = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc,idfield)] #List all ids
idcount = times_so_far(ids) #List their count
c = 0
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,updatefield) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[0]=idcount[c]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
        c+=1
```

The function comes from: [Count how many times values has appeared in list so far](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/118290/count-how-many-times-values-has-appeared-in-list-so-far)
[image]

Comment: Getting this error: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 19, in <module>
StopIteration: iteration not started

Comment: @forci020 try again! (I have no test data to try it on)